# PHP - How to remove specific character at a string?

Tags: php

i have more + symbol in my string and i want to remove last one and any character after it 
ex 
Giza+badrashen+test

Answer (score 2):

You can `explode` your string on `'+'` and then `join` it ignoring the last element of the split (with `array_slice` with negative index), like this (assuming `$str` is your string)

```
$result = join('', array_slice(explode('+', $str), -1));
```

In case you suspect your string may not contain a `'+'`, you can check for its presence first with `strpos`

```
if(strpos($str, '+') !== false) {
    $result = join('', array_slice(explode('+', $str), -1));
}
```

Comment: that would fail if it doesn't have a "+"

Answer (score 0):

```
 $string = "abc1234+12+3455+xzyabc";
 $string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string,"+"));
 echo $string;

> abc1234+12+3455
```

**EDIT:** and gives an empty string if there is no `+` but it doesn't crash/fail

**EDIT2:**  I slightly mis-read the question the first time, my edited answer is even simpler

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex solution:

Assuming you have `Giza+badrashen+test` and want `Giza+badrashen` as result.

```
echo preg_replace("/\+[^\+]*$/", "", "Giza+badrashen+test");
```

Tests:

```
var_dump(preg_replace("/\+[^\+]*$/", "", "Giza+badrashen+test"));
var_dump(preg_replace("/\+[^\+]*$/", "", "Giza+badrashen+test+"));
var_dump(preg_replace("/\+[^\+]*$/", "", "Giza"));
```

Output:

```
string(14) "Giza+badrashen"
string(19) "Giza+badrashen+test"
string(4) "Giza"
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex with a negative lookahead might be the most compact solution:

```
    $myString="foo-bar+foo+foobar";
    $result = preg_split("/\+(?!.*\+)/", $myString);
    echo $result[0];

//result:  foo-bar+foo
```

No need of additional check, cause in case no `+` is found it just gives back the original string.

It's just worth pointing that the `+` must be escaped having special meaning in all flowers of regex...